# Convert GET Method to POST Method in Flask

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I am building a simple web app to control leds in my Raspberry Pi.

I have a route and function call for them like following:

```
@app.route("/<pin>/<action>")
def action(pin, action):
    if pin == "pin1" and action == "on":
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)

    if pin == "pin1" and action == "off":
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
```

As by default Flask consider it GET method, I am using href with anchor tag in HTML file to pass the pin and action.

```
<button><a href="/pin1/on">ON</a></button>
<button><a href="/pin2/off">Off</a></button>
```

This works fine to turn on turn off the LED but it changes the URL after clicking on button. e.g. http://0.0.0.0/pin1/on and http://0.0.0.0/pin1/off

I don't want the URL to change so the POST method is suggested with form element using action and name in button. So, I tried following but it doesn't work. Python codes are

```
@app.route("/pinstatus", methods=['POST'])
def pinstatus():
    if request.form['lighton']:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)

    if request.form['lightoff']:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)
```

HTML Codes

```
<form action="{{ url_for('pinstatus') }}" method="POST">    
    <button name="lighton">ON</button>
    <button name="lightoff">Off</button>
</form>
```

I am seeking help on above situation. Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to set `SERVER_NAME` as documented [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/)

Comment: Why dont u redirect user after turning on/off to the page it was? Its a famous pattern for doing such a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's not too late.

Here is what you need to do. I am just tweaking your Python codes below and using jQuery to send data in POST method.

1) In your `server.py` or `app.py` file make a function like the following:

```
@app.route("/<pinstatus>/<int:pin>", methods=['POST'])
def action(pinstatus, pin):
    # Check the value of the parameter: 0 means Off, 1 means On
    if pinstatus == "light" and pin == 0:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH) 
    elif pinstatus == "light" and pin == 1:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        return ('Error', 500)
    return ('', 200)
```

2) Load jQuery in your static templates of Flask. e.g.: 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

3) Use following JS codes inside `<head>` element or some script file like `static/js/script.js`and load it in your HTML file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#lighton').click(function() {
        $.post('/light/1');
      });
      $('#lightoff').click(function() {
        $.post('/light/0');
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

4) Use HTML like the following:

```
<button id="lighton">On</button>             
<button id="lightoff">Off</button>
```

Now, it sends the data in POST method to the server and the URL doesn't change in the client-side. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to fire an XHR from the frontend when an user clicks on a button.

For example:
`<button><a onclick='pinAction("/pin1/on");'>ON</a></button>`

Then in JS do:

```
<script>
function pinAction(endpoint) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", endpoint, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send();
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText); // Maybe send a 200 reply
    return false; // So the default is prevented.
}
</script>
```

Then in the Flask backend you can keep using the same structure without having to use forms.